# Dependant selects question

Tags: forms, onchange

Below is a working example of a form. I need to display additional text field if user selects "Other" in drop down menu.

Unfortunately, I can't use example below because it requires Mootools but I use Jquery. Don't want to force users to download one more file (Mootools) just for one form.

Is there any way how to do this without Mootools? Thanks.

```
<form action='user_friends_manage.php' method='POST'>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<select name='friend_type' onChange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'other_friendtype') { $('other').style.display = 'block'; } else { $('other').style.display = 'none'; }">
<option></option>
<option value='1'>Friend</option>
<option value='2'>Family</option>
<option value='other_friendtype'>Other</option></select>
</td>
<td class='form2' style='display: none;' id='other'>&nbsp;<input type='text' class='text' name='friend_type_other' maxlength='50' /></td>
</tr></table></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
*if(this.value=='other_friendtype') {document.getElementById('other').style.display='block'}*

in onchage event of select control.